# docker Cannot find module when building image

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, npm, docker-compose

I'm creating a nodeJS Typescript project and trying to create a docker image of the project. The project successfully compiles on local, but when I try building the docker image (using either `docker build` or `docker-compose up`) it fails spectacularly because it 'Cannot find module x'.

The stranger thing is, when I tried adding `RUN npm ls <module>` to my dockerfile, it shows that the module was successfully installed. I've seen other questions here that include removing the `volume` in the docker-compose file, but since mine doesn't even have it to begin with, I'm lost.

I'm trying to do all of this on a Windows machine, if that helps.

Thanks in advance!

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
    image: app-nodejs
    container_name: appnodejs
```

**dockerfile**

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
USER root
ENV PORT 3000
RUN npm install -g pm2 typescript
RUN mkdir -p /app
COPY . /app/
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE ${PORT}
CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "start", "/app/ecosystem.config.js" ]
```

Edit:
I forgot to mention that it fails at npm run build, but all I'm doing there is running tsc. I can confirm that my tsconfig was properly copied since it returns the 'Cannot find module' error when I try to compile

Comment: try giving the absolute path to pm2-runtime in CMD in dockerfile

Comment: Sorry I realized I didn't explain where it fails. It fails at npm run build, but all I'm doing there is using tsc. I can confirm that my tsconfig was properly copied because it fails to compile with the 'cannot find module' error

Comment: can you add the error trace also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was caused by the missing module namely MomentJS
https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/5494
After either rolling back or updating to 2.25.1, the issue seems to have been resolved